# C# Devexpress : GridControl Add Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, devexpress

I need to change the cell editor to ComboBox. I want a specific cell to change ComboBox in the gridControl1?

[Check the desired functionality - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3p9w.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you go through the documentation - [Assigning Editors to Individual Cells](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument747)

> At runtime, you can assign editors to individual cells by handling the
>   [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic.aspx) (or [LayoutView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsLayoutLayoutView_CustomRowCellEdittopic.aspx))
>   event. The event occurs dynamically for each visible cell and allows
>   you to supply an editor to individual cells, based on the position of
>   the cell (its column and row).

example:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Column.FieldName != "ShipCity") return;
   GridView gv = sender as GridView;
   string fieldValue = gv.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle,gv.Columns["ShipCountry"]).ToString();
   switch (fieldValue) {
      case "France":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;
         break;
      case "USA":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox2;
         break;
   }
}
```